# Get an accurate value of Range Inputs onmousemovebase on the mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mousemove, onmousemove

How can you get the value of range input based on the cursor position on mousemove?
Something like this;

```js
$('.range').on('mousemove', function(){
    var rangeValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(rangeValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range">
```

Comment: Do you need the currently selected value or the minimum and maximum values?

Answer (score 1):

To get the current value where the mouse is hovering over the `input`, you can use the `offsetX` of the `event` and calculate the position like so:

```js
$('.range').on('mousemove', function(e){
    const offset = (e.offsetX / e.target.clientWidth) *  parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('max'),10);
    console.log('Hover place: ' + Math.round(offset) + '%');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range">
```

Comment: Does it give you an accurate value if the max attribute of the range input is big?

Comment: You should check for yourself, however, when setting `max='1000'` Im quite pleased with how accurate it is.

Comment: Is there anyway to get more accurate value when setting max='10000' ?

Comment: Nope, not like so. My solution calculates the value based on the mouse position relative to the size of the `input`. If the `input` is quite small (<100px) but the max value is huge (>1000) the value won't be that accurate, you should increase the size of the `input` to get a more precise value.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code works if you move the mouse only over the range element. To get it to work throughout your webpage you need

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(){
    var rangeValue = $('.range').val();
    console.log(rangeValue);
});
```

If you're trying to get the value of the slider when you **move** the slider, you can use .change just like with any other input.

Comment: Thank you, But I want the value of the range input from the cursor position

Comment: @EmmaGrove I don't know what you mean by this. You want to set the value based on the cursor position? Please clarify the question or zoom out a little bit and let us know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want the value based on cursor position.

Comment: @EmmaGrove cursor position on the screen has an X and a Y component. Are you just wanting to know how to change the value of the slider by clicking and dragging it?